# Sort list by key name

Tags: python

I have the following data structure (coming from a piece of code I can't modify):

```
{
 'key2':[{'name':'Oliver','value':1}, {'name':'Rambo','value':2}],
 'key1':[{'name':'Robert','value':4}, {'name':'Rambo','value':0}],
 'Ali':[{'name':'Oliver','value':1}, {'name':'Robert','value':0}]
}
```

I want to sort this list by 'key name' and not by key value. So if I apply a sort on the previous list the output should be:

```
{
 'Ali':[{'name':'Oliver','value':1}, {'name':'Robert','value':0}],
 'key1':[{'name':'Robert','value':4}, {'name':'Rambo','value':0}],
 'key2':[{'name':'Oliver','value':1}, {'name':'Rambo','value':2}]
}
```

I found a lot of litterature about how sorting by key value, but almost nothing regarding sorting by key name. What is the most efficient method to do that?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'key name', and it is unclear to me how you understand the concept. There is another problem here: Dictionaries are not ordered, you cannot sort them.

Comment: You can enumerate the keys and / or values and sort that enumeration, but I still don't know how your output is sorted. On the value associated with the `name` key found in the last dictionary from the value perhaps?

Comment: Well, I mean I want to sort it key attribute name : 'Ali', 'key1' ,'key2' ... I was thinking converting it to a list and then using sorted() on it. But I can't figure out how. Because here, the attribute name is the data I want to sort.

Comment: In any case, any of the 'sort dictionary by value' questions here on SO should provide you with an answer, like [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/613183). You need to provide a sort key function that'll return the think you want to sort on.

Comment: Ah, so you are sorting by *key* then. That's just the key, not a 'key name'.

Comment: You change the representation of the dictionary to sort it, but then the output will not be like you said.  Your output is a dictionary, and dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: If you want to know why dictionaries are listed like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68

Comment: you could take a look at the sorted containers library : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers/0.6.0 [I'm not affiliated to the sorted container library in any way]